# An event with unit density still has zero information, despite not being an event that is guaranteed to occur.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, machine-learning, information-theory, density-function

My textbook says the following in a section on **information theory**:

> The basic intuition behind information theory is that learning that an unlikely event has occurred is more informative than learning that a likely event has occurred. A message saying “the sun rose this morning” is so uninformative as to be unnecessary to send, but a message saying “there was a solar eclipse this morning” is very informative.
>
> We would like to quantify information in a way that formalizes this intuition.
>
> • Likely events should have low information content, and in the extreme case, events that are guaranteed to happen should have no information content whatsoever.
>
> • Less likely events should have higher information content.
>
> • Independent events should have additive information. For example, finding out that a tossed coin has come up as heads twice should convey twice as much information as finding out that a tossed coin has come up as heads once. To satisfy all three of these properties, we define the self-information of an event $\mathrm{x} = x$ to be
>
> $$I(x) = -\log(P(x))$$
>
> In this book, we always use $\log$ to mean the natural logarithm, with base $e$. Our definition of $I(x)$ is therefore written in units of nats. One nat is the amount of information gained by observing an event of probability $\dfrac{1}{e}$. Other texts use base-$2$ logarithms and units called bits or shannons; information measured in bits is just a rescaling of information measured in nats.
>
> When $\mathrm{x}$ is continuous, we use the same definition of information by analogy, but some of the properties from the discrete case are lost. For example, an event with unit density still has zero information, despite not being an event that is guaranteed to occur.

*Goodfellow, Ian; Bengio, Yoshua; Courville, Aaron. Deep Learning (Page 71).*

My question is about this last part:

> When $\mathrm{x}$ is continuous, we use the same definition of information by analogy, but some of the properties from the discrete case are lost. For example, an event with unit density still has zero information, despite not being an event that is guaranteed to occur.

1. What is meant by "unit density"?
2. What is meant by "an event with unit density"?
3. What is meant by "an event with unit density still has zero information, despite not being an event that is guaranteed to occur"?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: An event with probability 1 (aka. "almost sure"), for example "$X$ is irrational" for a uniformly distributed $X\in[0,1]$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen This is in the context of a continuous random variable. A density of $1$, $p(x) = 1$ (or $f_{\mathrm{x}}(x) = 1$), for a continuous random variable is not guaranteed to occur -- that is only true in the context of discrete random variables. I think you're confusing probability with density?

Comment: And I think I might have just answered my own question in the above comment?

Comment: $I(x) = -\log(1) \Rightarrow I(x) = 0$, and so it has zero information. And that answers 3.

Comment: I should also note that $P(x)$ in the textbook denotes a probability mass function, whilst $p(x)$ denotes a probability density function.

Comment: @ThePointer Any update on this? Why isn't an event with unit density guaranteed to occur? I would've thought it should be guaranteed.

Comment: @harinsa I will explain the reasoning that I came up with to justify the textbook's claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since @harinsa requested an update in the comments, I will methodically answer my question with the reasoning that I came up with to justify the textbook's claims:

1. Unit density means $p(x) = 1$, where $p(\cdot)$ is a probability density function and $x$ is a continuous random variable.
2. An event with unit density has zero information: $$\begin{align} I(x) &= -\log(p(x)) \\ &= -\log(1) \\ &= 0 \end{align}$$
3. This is despite it not being an even that is guaranteed to occur. In fact, it is an even that has $0$ probability of occurring, since the cumulative density function of such a PDF is zero: $$\begin{align} &p(x) = 1 \\ \therefore \ &P(x) = 0 \ , \end{align}$$ where $P(x)$ here represents the cumulative density function, as opposed to in the textbook, where the author uses it to represent the probability mass function. This is because the probability of a continuous random variable being equal to any specific value (rather than a continuous range of real values) is zero.

Comment: Would you please provide some authoritative sources about unit density?

Comment: @fuDL What do you mean “about unit density”? “Unit density” is just terminology that refers to the concept I explained in 1. in my answer above. The terminology is analogous to “unit integral” in other mathematical contexts, which just refers to the integer 1.

Comment: What is the difference between "Unit density means ()=1" and other regular probability density function which is also equal to 1.

Comment: Consider the simplest model, the Bernoulli distribution, toss a coin. {head, tail}, the probability of {head, tail} (either a head or a tail} is equal to 1. Is the "1" the unit density?

Comment: @fuDL you ask a good question. What you’re missing is that a probability density function is only defined for *continuous* random variables. What you’ve defined in the Bernoulli distribution case is a Bernoulli distributed random variable, which is a type of *discrete* random variable. So the term “unit density” makes no sense in your Bernoulli example, because probability density functions are only defined for continuous random variables. In the case of discrete random variables, the analogous concept is the **probability mass function**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How about standard normal distribution over real number space?

Comment: @fuDL normally distributed random variables are *continuous* random variables. But what do you mean "over real number space"? This doesn't make sense and is a meaningless statement. The probability density function is a function whose value at any given sample in the sample space can be interpreted as giving the *relative likelihood* that the value of the random variable would equal that sample (see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). I think that you need to start studying these concepts from the beginning, to make sure that you're not misunderstanding them.